# how to assign different activities to each item of the spinner?

Tags: java, android

I have a page which consist of a spinner and a submit button. What I want to achieve is when user selects an item in the list and click on submit, it should take him to an other layout having a webview. Each item in the spinner should open different .html page in the layout.

What I have now is the item is being selected from the spinner, but I'm not sure how to perform onclick listener to it...

code for main activity is here

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beef);


        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }


    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    //get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        btnSubmit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Nothing as of now*/
                //I need to call the ID of the selected item from the spinner here and start new activity
            }

        });

    }

}
```

code of CustomOnItemSelectedListener is here

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (arg2 == 0) // First item selected
    {
    //Here I need to give an id for the .html file  

    }
    else if (arg2 == 1) // Second
    {
            //Here I need to give an id for the .html file  
    }



    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    String selItem = arg0.get(arg2); // String representation of the selected item

    if (arg2 == 0) // First item selected
    {

    }
    else if (arg2 == 1) // Second
    {

    }
    // etc
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```